# Why last symbol of a text starts a new line?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to find a way to fix bug in Chrome 49 on Mac, and keep functionality provided by **display: inline-block;** and **word-break: break-all;**

Any suggestions?

[Screenshot of a problem](https://s.mail.ru/46gw7DyzTA2m/img-2016-03-14-13-27-04.png)

Problem is actual not for any text, but for many strings in my app.

```css
.test{
    color: #333;
    display: inline-block;
}

.wrap{
  word-break: break-all;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
<span class="wrap">
<a href="#" class="test" target="_blank">Просмотры куб</a>
</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I stimulate your problem, looks there is a problem with `<span>` or `font-family`, i find two ways to localize problem, you can change font-family to 'Helvetica' or change `<span>` tag to `<p>`.

You can report this but to chrome. ;)

Comment: looks no always changing tag is working, in your case you cant change `<a>` to `<span>` :)

Comment: i can't give you the best solution becouse i dont see your html layout, you can change layout, make `<a> display:block;` and lot of other whings to avoid a problem, its up to you :)